# How can I make checklist counters accumulate results from subheaders in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to do something like this in Emacs' Org-mode:

```
* headline [%]
** subheadline1 [%]
   - [ ] list item 1
   - [ ] list item 2
** subheadline2 [%]
   - [ ] list item 1
   - [ ] list item 2
```

The purpose here is to have the percentage cookie at headline present the total percentage of completed tasks computed from the percentage cookies of its subheadlines.

If "subheadline1" is at **40**%, and "subheadline2" is at **50**%, then "headline" should be at **(40 + 50) / 2 = 45** % (**2** is the number of subheadlines).

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: its not clear (at least for me) what you want. what you want to achieve finally from that template?

Comment: @kindahero Posted a more elaborate explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that is entirely possible at the moment.  Checkboxes deal with their children only by default as a complete/incomplete cookie.  (See [Checkboxes](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Checkboxes)).  However there is the option to use `org-checkbox-hierarchical-statistics` and include all checkboxes in the headline, not just direct children.

So by adding or evaluating

```lisp
(setq org-checkbox-hierarchical-statistics nil)
```

You can set this feature (count all checkboxes in tree, recursively) for all org-files.

If you want to set it for specific trees only, the docstring provides the answer:

```
org-checkbox-hierarchical-statistics is a variable defined in `org-list.el'.
Its value is t

Documentation:
Non-nil means checkbox statistics counts only the state of direct children.
When nil, all boxes below the cookie are counted.
This can be set to nil on a per-node basis using a COOKIE_DATA property
with the word "recursive" in the value.
```

In this case your example would become:

```
* headline [%]
:PROPERTIES:
:COOKIE_DATA: recursive
:END:
** subheadline1 [%]
   - [ ] list item 1
   - [ ] list item 2
** subheadline2 [%]
   - [ ] list item 1
   - [ ] list item 2
```

To use your further example:
Subheadline 1 = 2/4 = 50%
Subheadline 2 = 2/5 = 45%
Headline 1 = 4/9 = 44.44%

Comment: Is it expected that it notworks right now ? (I use the `COOKIE_DATA recursive` property and it stays at 0/0 instead of expected 2/8)

Comment: @Jonathan - Is there a way if you have it set to be recursive by default to get the non-recursive behavior back by setting certain subtrees with a COOKIE_DATA?

Comment: Note that the variable has been [inexplicably changed](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/f373bca58b8fe665739815c2b7174dc91e2a9c0c) to `org-checkbox-hierarchical-statistics`. The [docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html#DOCF51), however, have **not** been changed.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The only solution is to have the same type of item, either all headers or all list items. So in this example, changing the `-` by `***` or the `**` by `-`